# append ajax variable to existing select box

Tags: jquery

First i call a form which is in an overlay and if the user is happy with the choices in the dropdown, they can just add a new record. but if they want to add a choice, they click "add" which then opens a javascript prompt.  this prompt submits to mysql using ajax and if it's a success, i want the new choice to become the "selected" choice in the dropdown in the overlay.  I can make the alert show the val but cannot figure out how to make the dropdown update with this is a new choice.  the select box is just a standard html 
`<select name="User_level" id="User_level">`

```
if(response.success == "1"){

    $(".User_level").append("<option value=\"test\">test</option>");        

}
```

This didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the code that makes the AJAX request?

Comment: Try `alert` on success, to make sure that your code actually gets executed.

Comment: `function AddNewUserLevel() {
 var val=prompt("Enter new user level here");


      
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET", 
   url: "uemployees_addlevel_ajax.php?level=" + val, 
      dataType: "json",
   success: function(response){
    if(response.success == "1"){

      $("#p" + response.p.id).data("critical", data.p.critical);     
    }
   },

  });

 }`

Comment: i can do an alert and see the variable. just can't get the select box to show the updated option

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO `user_levels` (level) VALUES ('$level')";
mysql_query($sql);
  echo json_encode(
   array(
    "success" => "1",
    )
  );